# Force Client Window to be rendered to bigger screen

Tags: league-of-legends, windows-8

So i have 2 Screens. one smaller and one larger. i made the smaller one my "primary" screen and started LOL. then i took the patcher to the larger screen. after pressing play, the PVP.NET-Client was rendered to my Main Screen (the smaller, "primary") again. Again i moved him to the larger screen. when the game started, the Client was rendered to the smaller screen with the resolution of the bigger screen(!). someone has an idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: Try going into your monitor settings in the control panel and making sure the larger screen is considered the "Primary".

Comment: He's right, I do this at work

Comment: sorry i was unexact. i made the smaller my primary. the funny thing is, that on every other game i play, if i move the launcher instance to the bigger, not-primary screen, the main window gets rendered there...

Comment: At least for me, the game always jumps to the "Primary" screen no matter where I put the launcher.  You might just have to change that to your primary screen to play LoL.  At least it's not hard to change back.

Comment: @AaronBrown yes that may be true,but it still bugs me i need to do that only to play LoL and for nothing else...

Comment: The reason why LoL is launched in primary is because the game client closes and opens automatically. If it is possible to set the screen for the league of legends game you need to manually close the client in the window you want it to open. Since this is done automatically it will not save the settings on which screen it should launch.

Comment: @Vogel612 Couldn't you just when the game has started, put fullscreen off drag and put fullscreen back on again?

Comment: @Lyrion that does help, but the problem is. i do not really want to waste 15-30 secs every start of game going to video settings, enabling window mode, pull the window, enable fullscreen mode and adjust resolution.

Comment: @Vogel612 Now i don't know for lol and such. But loads of programs i use, remember what screen they were set too... Now i don't know if this application specific or windows specific. For example chrome, if i drag chrome to the other screen, close and then open again it will open in that window again. If lol does this too, i think if you switch it once, it will remember.

Comment: @Lyrion i think this is application-specific, as i have seen different behavior with different applications. and lol seems to be one of the dumb applications...

Comment: @Vogel612 Ah but did you try it? That is the main question :p

Comment: @Lyrion of course i did, else i would not tell you this.. i am software developer in training i know how to do such things as reporting bugs and observing application behavior ;) also it is quite a bad idea to try close and reopen the questioned window, as in that case you will need to reconnect and automatically a different instance of the program will be rendered...

Comment: @Vogel612 Hmm ok, have you checked in the ...\lol\Config\game.cfg ? Maybe you can force it there via a setting but I don't know, i work with 2 monitors. But at home i play one 1 big ass monitor so never had the problem :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of the launcher has no bearing on where the game will display. If you are playing in fullscreen mode it will default to your primary monitor. Some games have the options to set the monitor you are wanting to use, this is normally located under options > video.

Comment: is not the case here unforunately --> closed as not possible